# Modeling a stadium dome with UVs?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, uv

Beginning with Blender, I would like to create a stadium dome like the following one:

[image]

This is how it looks when textured:

[image]

This is the texture used:

[image]

This is the UV mapping:

[image]

Now you may ask why I don't reuse that model? It's because I'd like to assign a texture with different dimensions so the original UV mapping wouldn't be right. So while I'm on it, I'd rather learn the entire process on how to do it.

**Edit:**

For instance, I'd like to map it to a texture like the following:

[image]

In this case, I would like to map the lower half, so the mountains and a little above to the straightened part of the dome, and map the rest to the spherical part.

**Question:**

How could I recreate more or less the same dome in Blender?

Comment: Create sphere, extrude from middle down.

Comment: Okay, I've got a sphere, selected those vertices, when pulling them down using Extrude Region it starts looking like a capsule. Not sure what to do next so they all look straight...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very easy thing to make in Blender.

Step one- Take a sphere and select the bottom half faces, then delete that part.
You can now scale the top half of the sphere on the Z axis to look slightly less spherical.

Step two- In Edit Mode select the bottom-most edges of the half-sphere and press <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd> to extrude it down on the Z axis, then type "-.1" to move the extruded part down just a bit, then press <kbd>Enter/return</kbd>

Step three- Before doing anything else, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to repeat the action. This will extrude another part 0.1 down the Z axis off of the already extruded part. For reference, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is the hotkey you use in Blender to repeat the previous action.

Image of result for reference:
[image]

This should get the result you want.

**EDIT** If you want to unwrap a UV texture to your model, then you have to give the object a **[material](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/materials/index.html)**, and add an **[image texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/image.html?highlight=image%20texture)** with the image you want to the color input of the material node.

Comment: This is a great answer, the only part I still couldn't figure out is how to map UVs.

Comment: I've added an example of a texture I would like to map it to, thank you 